# Android Geofence only works with opened app

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-geofence

I'm doing a serious research on this topic for many days... I saw many topics here too...
But unfortunately I couldn't find a solution....

I'm writing an app that uses the new Google API for Geofence...
Well, I can handle "ins" and "outs" of a geofence, but only if my app is open! Even if I'm with wifi on, gps on, and 3G on, but the app, it does not trigger any event...Just if the app is open...

I'm using exactly the same GeofenceRequester class of the documentation http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html .

Even the class been the same I'll post the code here:

```
package br.com.marrs.imhere.geofence;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import br.com.marrs.imhere.services.ReceiveTransitionsIntentService;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationStatusCodes;

/**
 * Class for connecting to Location Services and requesting geofences.
 * <b>
 * Note: Clients must ensure that Google Play services is available before requesting geofences.
 * </b> Use GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() to check.
 *
 *
 * To use a GeofenceRequester, instantiate it and call AddGeofence(). Everything else is done
 * automatically.
 *
 */
public class GeofenceRequester
                implements
                    OnAddGeofencesResultListener,
                    ConnectionCallbacks,
                    OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Storage for a reference to the calling client
    private final Activity mActivity;

    // Stores the PendingIntent used to send geofence transitions back to the app
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

    // Stores the current list of geofences
    private ArrayList<Geofence> mCurrentGeofences;

    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;

    /*
     * Flag that indicates whether an add or remove request is underway. Check this
     * flag before attempting to start a new request.
     */
    private boolean mInProgress;

    public GeofenceRequester(Activity activityContext) {
        // Save the context
        mActivity = activityContext;

        // Initialize the globals to null
        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
        mLocationClient = null;
        mInProgress = false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the "in progress" flag from a caller. This allows callers to re-set a
     * request that failed but was later fixed.
     *
     * @param flag Turn the in progress flag on or off.
     */
    public void setInProgressFlag(boolean flag) {
        // Set the "In Progress" flag.
        mInProgress = flag;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current in progress status.
     *
     * @return The current value of the in progress flag.
     */
    public boolean getInProgressFlag() {
        return mInProgress;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current PendingIntent to the caller.
     *
     * @return The PendingIntent used to create the current set of geofences
     */
    public PendingIntent getRequestPendingIntent() {
        return createRequestPendingIntent();
    }

    /**
     * Start adding geofences. Save the geofences, then start adding them by requesting a
     * connection
     *
     * @param geofences A List of one or more geofences to add
     */
    public void addGeofences(List<Geofence> geofences) throws UnsupportedOperationException {

        /*
         * Save the geofences so that they can be sent to Location Services once the
         * connection is available.
         */
        mCurrentGeofences = (ArrayList<Geofence>) geofences;

        // If a request is not already in progress
        if (!mInProgress) {

            // Toggle the flag and continue
            mInProgress = true;

            // Request a connection to Location Services
            requestConnection();

        // If a request is in progress
        } else {

            // Throw an exception and stop the request
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Request a connection to Location Services. This call returns immediately,
     * but the request is not complete until onConnected() or onConnectionFailure() is called.
     */
    private void requestConnection() 
    {
        getLocationClient().connect();
    }

    /**
     * Get the current location client, or create a new one if necessary.
     *
     * @return A LocationClient object
     */
    private GooglePlayServicesClient getLocationClient()
    {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {

            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mActivity, this, this);
        }
        return mLocationClient;

    }
    /**
     * Once the connection is available, send a request to add the Geofences
     */
    private void continueAddGeofences() {

        // Get a PendingIntent that Location Services issues when a geofence transition occurs
        mGeofencePendingIntent = createRequestPendingIntent();

        // Send a request to add the current geofences
        mLocationClient.addGeofences(mCurrentGeofences, mGeofencePendingIntent, this);
    }

    /*
     * Handle the result of adding the geofences
     */
    @Override
    public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds) 
    {
        // Create a broadcast Intent that notifies other components of success or failure
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        // Temp storage for messages
        String msg;

        // If adding the geocodes was successful
        if (LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS == statusCode) 
        {
            // Create a message containing all the geofence IDs added.
            msg = geofenceRequestIds.toString();

            // In debug mode, log the result
            Log.d("DEBUG", msg);

            // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
            broadcastIntent.setAction("br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED")
                           .addCategory("br.com.marrs.imhere.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES")
                           .putExtra("br.com.marrs.imhere.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS", msg);
        // If adding the geofences failed
        } 
        else
        {

            /*
             * Create a message containing the error code and the list
             * of geofence IDs you tried to add
             */
            msg = "Erro adicionando geofence";

            // Log an error
            Log.e("DEBUG", msg);

            // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
            broadcastIntent.setAction("br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR")
                           .addCategory("br.com.marrs.imhere.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES")
                           .putExtra("br.com.marrs.imhere.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS", msg);
        }

        // Broadcast whichever result occurred
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        // Disconnect the location client
        requestDisconnection();
    }

    /**
     * Get a location client and disconnect from Location Services
     */
    private void requestDisconnection() {

        // A request is no longer in progress
        mInProgress = false;

        getLocationClient().disconnect();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services once the location client is connected.
     *
     * Continue by adding the requested geofences.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // If debugging, log the connection

        Log.d("DEBUG", "GeofenceRequester connected");

        // Continue adding the geofences
        continueAddGeofences();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services once the location client is disconnected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {


        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;

        // In debug mode, log the disconnection
        Log.d("DEBUG", "GeofenceRequester disconnected");

        // Destroy the current location client
        mLocationClient = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a PendingIntent to send with the request to add Geofences. Location Services issues
     * the Intent inside this PendingIntent whenever a geofence transition occurs for the current
     * list of geofences.
     *
     * @return A PendingIntent for the IntentService that handles geofence transitions.
     */
    private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {

        // If the PendingIntent already exists
        if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {

            // Return the existing intent
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;

        // If no PendingIntent exists
        } else {

            // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
            /*
             * Return a PendingIntent to start the IntentService.
             * Always create a PendingIntent sent to Location Services
             * with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, so that sending the PendingIntent
             * again updates the original. Otherwise, Location Services
             * can't match the PendingIntent to requests made with it.
             */
            return PendingIntent.getService(
                    mActivity,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Implementation of OnConnectionFailedListener.onConnectionFailed
     * If a connection or disconnection request fails, report the error
     * connectionResult is passed in from Location Services
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;

        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, 9000);

            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        /*
         * If no resolution is available, put the error code in
         * an error Intent and broadcast it back to the main Activity.
         * The Activity then displays an error dialog.
         * is out of date.
         */
        } else {

            Intent errorBroadcastIntent = new Intent("br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_CONNECTION_ERROR");
            errorBroadcastIntent.addCategory("br.com.marrs.imhere.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES")
                                .putExtra("br.com.marrs.imhere.EXTRA_CONNECTION_ERROR_CODE",
                                        connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(errorBroadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
package br.com.marrs.imhere.services;
import br.com.marrs.imhere.ImHereActivity;
import br.com.marrs.imhere.R;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class receives geofence transition events from Location Services, in the
 * form of an Intent containing the transition type and geofence id(s) that triggered
 * the event.
 */
public class ReceiveTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Sets an identifier for this class' background thread
     */
    public ReceiveTransitionsIntentService() 
    {
        super("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService");
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents
     * @param intent The Intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided
     * to Location Services (inside a PendingIntent) when you call addGeofences()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Create a local broadcast Intent
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        // Give it the category for all intents sent by the Intent Service
        broadcastIntent.addCategory("br.com.marrs.imhere.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES");

        // First check for errors
        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {

            // Get the error code
            int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);


            // Log the error
            Log.e("DEBUG", "Erro no service LocationClient has error");

            // Set the action and error message for the broadcast intent
            broadcastIntent.setAction("br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ERROR").putExtra("br.com.marrs.imhere.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS", "problemas");

            // Broadcast the error *locally* to other components in this app
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        // If there's no error, get the transition type and create a notification
        } else {

            // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
            int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

            // Test that a valid transition was reported
            if (
                    (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    ||
                    (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
               ) {

                // Post a notification
                List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
                String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
                for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size() ; index++) {
                    geofenceIds[index] = geofences.get(index).getRequestId();
                }
                String ids = TextUtils.join(",",geofenceIds);
                String transitionType = getTransitionString(transition);

                sendNotification(transitionType, ids);

                // Log the transition type and a message
                Log.d("DEBUG","Ae...n sei pq isso....mas parece que tah ok");

            // An invalid transition was reported
            } else {
                // Always log as an error
                Log.e("DEBUG","Erro, erro, erro");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
     * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the main Activity.
     * @param transitionType The type of transition that occurred.
     *
     */
    private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String ids)
    {

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent =
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImHereActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ImHereActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Set the notification contents
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_clear)
               .setContentTitle(ids)
               .setContentText(transitionType)
               .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    /**
     * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
     * @param transitionType A transition type constant defined in Geofence
     * @return A String indicating the type of transition
     */
    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {

            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return "Entrando";

            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return "Saindo";

            default:
                return "Desconhecido";
        }
    }
}
```

And the Broadcast receiver in the Activity:

```
public class GeofenceSampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        /*
         * Define the required method for broadcast receivers
         * This method is invoked when a broadcast Intent triggers the receiver
         */
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {

            // Check the action code and determine what to do
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // Intent contains information about errors in adding or removing geofences
            if (TextUtils.equals(action, "br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR"))
            {

                handleGeofenceError(context, intent);

            // Intent contains information about successful addition or removal of geofences
            } 
            else if (
                    TextUtils.equals(action, "br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED")
                    ||
                    TextUtils.equals(action, "br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCES_REMOVED")) 
            {

                handleGeofenceStatus(context, intent);

            // Intent contains information about a geofence transition
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(action, "br.com.marrs.imhere.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION")) 
            {

                handleGeofenceTransition(context, intent);

            // The Intent contained an invalid action
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.e("DEBUG", "Invalid action detail");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid action detail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * If you want to display a UI message about adding or removing geofences, put it here.
         *
         * @param context A Context for this component
         * @param intent The received broadcast Intent
         */
        private void handleGeofenceStatus(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }

        /**
         * Report geofence transitions to the UI
         *
         * @param context A Context for this component
         * @param intent The Intent containing the transition
         */
        private void handleGeofenceTransition(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /*
             * If you want to change the UI when a transition occurs, put the code
             * here. The current design of the app uses a notification to inform the
             * user that a transition has occurred.
             */
        }

        /**
         * Report addition or removal errors to the UI, using a Toast
         *
         * @param intent A broadcast Intent sent by ReceiveTransitionsIntentService
         */
        private void handleGeofenceError(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("br.com.marrs.imhere.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS");
            Log.e("DEBUG", msg);
            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And here is the piece of code that I use to create a GEofence before send to GeofenceRequester.

```
int raio = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getAdapter().getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
            int transitionType = (in.isChecked())?Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT;
            Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId(nomeGeofence.getText().toString()).setTransitionTypes(transitionType).setCircularRegion(lat, lon, raio).setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE).build();
            geofences.add(geofence);

            try 
            {
                mGeofenceRequester.addGeofences(geofences);
                addCircleGeofence(raio);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Já existe uma requisição de add em andamento",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Any help will be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same exact [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents/19521823#19521823). Here is what I answered over there: So after playing around with this a bit, it looks like the ReceiveTransitionsIntentService (as defined in the sample code) will stop getting the notifications when the app is not around. I think this is a big problem with the example code... Seems like that will trip folks like me up.

So I used a broadcast receiver instead, and so far it seems to be working from my tests.

Add this to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.GeofenceReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in the GeofenceRequester class you need to change the createRequestPendingIntent method so that it goes to your BroadcastReceiver instead of the ReceiveTransitionsIntentService. MAKE SURE AND NOTE the change to .getBroadcast instead of getService. That got me hung up for a while.

```
private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {

        // If the PendingIntent already exists
        if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {

            // Return the existing intent
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;

        // If no PendingIntent exists
        } else {

            // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");

            //MAKE SURE YOU CHANGE THIS TO getBroadcast if you are coming from the sample code.
            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }
```

Then I added the GeofenceReceiver class that looks something like this:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            handleError(intent);
        } else {
            handleEnterExit(intent);
        }
    }

    private void handleError(Intent intent){
        // Get the error code
        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);

        // Get the error message
        String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
                context, errorCode);

        // Log the error
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_error_detail,
                        errorMessage));

        // Set the action and error message for the broadcast intent
        broadcastIntent
                .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);

        // Broadcast the error *locally* to other components in this app
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                broadcastIntent);
    }


    private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {
        // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
        int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

        // Test that a valid transition was reported
        if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

            // Post a notification
            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient
                    .getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
            String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER,
                    geofenceIds);
            String transitionType = GeofenceUtils
                    .getTransitionString(transition);

            for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size(); index++) {
                Geofence geofence = geofences.get(index);
                ...do something with the geofence entry or exit. I'm saving them to a local sqlite db

            }
            // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
            broadcastIntent
                    .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                    .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_ID, geofenceIds)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_TYPE,
                            transitionType);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext())
                    .sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            // Log the transition type and a message
            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, transitionType + ": " + ids);
            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

            // In debug mode, log the result
            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, "transition");

            // An invalid transition was reported
        } else {
            // Always log as an error
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                            transition));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is
     * detected. If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the main
     * Activity.
     * 
     * @param transitionType
     *            The type of transition that occurred.
     * 
     */
    private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String locationName) {

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

        // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions
        // >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);

        // Set the notification contents
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(transitionType + ": " + locationName)
                .setContentText(
                        context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone else.

Comment: hi, i downloaded and ran the geofence code from the developer website and it worked fine for me. The ReceiveTransitionService class is called even while the app is closed and it is a broadcastIntent which is getting fired in any case

Comment: the code doesnt work for me with the google sample and another example that I have

Comment: @b-ryce This code has been extremely useful to me, thank you for it! I was wondering though what "MyApplication.getContext()" was? Is it the context for the GeoFenceReciever.java or for you main fragment activity?

Comment: @b-ryce I know its been a while since you answered, but do you know if I need to request location updates in the background too? or will the geofence request for me?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and after trying various ways I could finally fix the issue. Unfortunately, the android documentation fails to mention these issues.
The android geofences get removed every time you reboot your device or every time you toggle the location mode.
So Add a broadcast receiver to listen to device reboots and location mode changes, and add the geofences again in the receiver.

I have posted a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773062/4657700)

Comment: this could have been a simple comment and the question could be marked duplicate?