# Geofences not working when app is killed

Tags: android, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence

I know similar questions have been asked before but answers were not perfect.

I created an app with geofences using the sample code from android developer website. I did not use any shared preferences to store geofences as I am not removing the geofences. I am testing the app from within the geofence, but my smartphone receives notifications every time the app runs and no notifications are observed when the app is killed. Why does this happen? I think I am supposed to receive notifications even when the app is killed.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    .....
GeofencingTask myTask = new GeofencingTask();
    myTask.execute();
}
private class GeofencingTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("1")

                .setCircularRegion(
                        Constants.MyAPP_LOCATION_LATITUDE,
                        Constants.MyAPP_LOCATION_LONGITUDE,
                        Constants.MyAPP_RADIUS
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_TIME)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build());
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        );

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while resolving connection error.", e);
            }
        } else {
            int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection to Google Play services failed with error code " + errorCode);
        }
    }

}
```

GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService{

String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIntentService";
int geofenceTransition;

public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    super("name");

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        int errorCode = geofencingEvent.getErrorCode();
        Log.e(TAG, "Location Services error: " + errorCode);
    }
    geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
        // multiple geofences.
        List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                this,
                geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences
        );
        Log.i("GeofenceTransitionDetails",geofenceTransitionDetails);

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        sendInOutsTask myTask = new sendInOutsTask();
        myTask.execute();

        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                geofenceTransition));
    }

}

private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
        Context context,
        int geofenceTransition,
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

    String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

    // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
    ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

    return geofenceTransitionString;

}

/**
 * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
 * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
 */
private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.zemoso_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.zemoso_logo))
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
    switch (transitionType) {
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
            return Constants.WELCOME_NOTIFICATION;
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
            return Constants.EXIT_NOTIFICATION;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please check this other question. Answered here:

[android geofence only works with opened app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434999/android-geofence-only-works-with-opened-app)

Comment: i have the same did you solved it i use the answer below but from broadcast the GeofenceTransationService is not calling am i doing some thing worng

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, May be a bit late but I'll post the answer on how I fixed this issue myself. Two things:

**1)** I was adding the geofences every time I run the MainActivity and geofences API triggers the geofencing event, if you add the geofences when you are already inside the specified geofence (i.e. starting the geofence app when you are already inside the geofence). 
So I changed my code in the onConnected method to add the geofences only if they are not added previously. (Implemented a check using Shared preferences)

```
 public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("GEO_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String geofencesExist = sharedPrefs.getString("Geofences added", null);

    if (geofencesExist == null) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent(this)
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>()            {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("GEO_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("Geofences added", "1");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**2)** Turns out the reasons for not receiving notifications when the app is not available were

i) Either I toggled location services in the device(on/off/battery saving/device only/high accuracy) at least once after I added the geofences or,

ii) The device was rebooted.

To overcome this, I have added a broadcast receiver to listen to device reboots and location services toggling. In the receiver, I am adding the geofences again if the device either rebooted or location services toggled.

```
 public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private static PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
Context contextBootReceiver;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


    contextBootReceiver = context;

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    if ((intent.getAction().equals("android.location.MODE_CHANGED") && isLocationModeAvailable(contextBootReceiver)) || (intent.getAction().equals("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED") && isLocationServciesAvailable(contextBootReceiver))) {
        // isLocationModeAvailable for API >=19, isLocationServciesAvailable for API <19
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("GEO_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.remove("Geofences added");
        editor.commit();
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services unavailable.");
            return;
        }

        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("1")

                .setCircularRegion(
                        Constants.MyAPP_LOCATION_LATITUDE,
                        Constants.MyAPP_LOCATION_LONGITUDE,
                        Constants.MyAPP_LOCATION_RADIUS
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_TIME)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setLoiteringDelay(30000)
                .build());


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(contextBootReceiver)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private boolean isLocationModeAvailable(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && getLocationMode(context) != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

public boolean isLocationServciesAvailable(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));

    }
    else return false;
}

public int getLocationMode(Context context) {
    try {
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = contextBootReceiver.getSharedPreferences("GEO_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String geofencesExist = sharedPrefs.getString("Geofences added", null);

    if (geofencesExist == null) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent(contextBootReceiver)
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = contextBootReceiver.getSharedPreferences("GEO_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("Geofences added", "1");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult((android.app.Activity) contextBootReceiver,
                    Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception while resolving connection error.", e);
        }
    } else {
        int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection to Google Play services failed with error code " + errorCode);
    }

}

@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {

}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(contextBootReceiver);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, (android.app.Activity) contextBootReceiver,
                    Constants.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}


static PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent(Context context) {

    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

}

Android Manifest

```
.
.
.
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.location.MODE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 .
 .
```

Comment: i use the same code but broadcast receiver not starting GeofenceTransitionsIntentServic any help?

Comment: ahhh i was GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL  and  it was trigring inital  notification i change it to GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER and it work thank you for the help

Comment: How did you store your latittude and longitude in your constants file, i'm currently storing mine in a hashmap: LANDMARKS.put("Test", new LatLng(-29.78976400000001,30.822186999999985));

So wouldnt be able to access them implementing the code you used

Comment: Hello I got   if((intent.getAction().equals("android.location.MODE_CHANGED") null pointer exception here.

Comment: it is better to check if the pending intent exists instead of writing in the sharedpreferences that you have added the geofences, because when you reboot the phone or change the location accuracy, they are removed and the pending intent does not exist anymore, but the sharedpreferences would not be updated