# Location (Geofence) Triggered Push Notifications in Unity Android Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, geofencing, geofire

My requirement is sending geofence triggered push notifications to users even if the app is killed or not running at the moment.

For example, a user entered Central Park in New York, I want to send push notifications to that user.

I don't know much about neither native android applications nor about andoid studio and grandle - java  things.

In my search I found that Firebase has a Firebase Cloud Messaging Unity Package and also GeoFire repos in github, but can not figure out how they works.

Android studio can export Unity plugins as .jar or .arr where you can call java - kotlin API's. But I can not figure out how to use these and set my locations to these native geofence applications.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I can try to guide you from a native perspective.
Did you follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773062/4158892)? and after this, I think you need to set GeofencingRequest to `GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER`

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can not follow these steps because when I import 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0' in android studio build grandle and build project as .arr library and import it to unity, Unity builds start giving me error due to play services I think.

I must make it a library and import it in Unity because If I make builds on Unity and import it in Android studio every time, that will be a problematic situation and huge waste of time every time.