# Show notification when User go to a specific location

Tags: android, location, location-services

I develop an android application which will show a notification when you near a specific location .

I want to give user a notification when user enter to a specific location even if my app is turn off.

How can I do that ? My friend give me a suggest that use a Broadcast Receiver but I don't know how to implement this .

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use geofencing. It is integrated in Android and very easy to use. Google has great [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) about the feature.

Comment: I do an exampe use Geofence , it run ok. But when turn off my app, it don't work ? Could you give me some suggestions ?

Comment: I would like to refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19573721/1702602). If you still can not figure it out, I think it is best to ask a separate question including some code. If you do so, you can comment a link to that question here.